# How to resolve React native error while copying template

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create react native app using react native cli but after downloading templates it is showing error

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Thakur\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-d9w32Z\node_modules\react-native\template.config'

I am using following command to create an app;

```
npx react-native init MyApp
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the react native cli

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

or

```
yarn global add react-native-cli
```

then

```
react-native run-android
```

or

```
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: I tried your solution but after creating app when I am trying to run it using `npm start` hen it gets stuck at `Loading dependency graph, done.`

Comment: react-native run-android

Comment: That's great
Now do it ````react-native run anadroid or run ios

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and discovered when I change my yarn version from 3.2 back to 1.22 using `yarn set version classic`, it worked well.
More info on setting yarn version can be found here https://yarnpkg.com/cli/set/version Hope this helps someone